# Hazelcast jet Python Exception: PythonService initialization failed

Tags: java, python, hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

While executing python function but it's not working:
Here is my code :

```
BatchStage<Object> bd1 = AggregateData.aggregate(data, Object);
bd1 = bd1.filter(k -> {
                    // some filters
                });
```

Here I am using BatchStage:

```
bd1.map(f3 -> f3.toString()).apply(PythonTransforms.mapUsingPythonBatch(new PythonServiceConfig()
                             .setBaseDir("D:/")
                             .setHandlerModule("take_sqrt")))
                     .setLocalParallelism(1)
                     .writeTo(Sinks.logger());
                      
                      JobConfig cfg = new JobConfig().setName("python-function");
                      jetInstance.newJob(pipeline, cfg);
```

Python code is simple to test this whole test:

```
import numpy as np
def transform_list(input_list):
    return input_list
```

But when I tried to run it, it gives me below exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: com.hazelcast.jet.JetException: PythonService initialization failed: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportJoin(CompletableFuture.java:412)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.join(CompletableFuture.java:2108)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.Job.join(Job.java:148)
    at com.aiv.hazelcast.Application.setUp(Application.java:100)
    at com.aiv.hazelcast.Application.main(Application.java:42)
Caused by: com.hazelcast.jet.JetException: PythonService initialization failed: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at com.hazelcast.jet.python.PythonServiceContext.<init>(PythonServiceContext.java:109)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.python.PythonService.createContextWithRetry(PythonService.java:110)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.python.PythonService.lambda$factory$9a0f8f23$1(PythonService.java:90)
    at com.hazelcast.function.FunctionEx.apply(FunctionEx.java:47)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.processor.ProcessorSupplierWithService.init(ProcessorSupplierWithService.java:55)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.execution.init.ExecutionPlan.initProcSuppliers(ExecutionPlan.java:319)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.execution.init.ExecutionPlan.initialize(ExecutionPlan.java:165)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.execution.ExecutionContext.initialize(ExecutionContext.java:138)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.JobExecutionService.lambda$initExecution$544ea571$1(JobExecutionService.java:241)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.function.RunnableEx.run(RunnableEx.java:30)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.util.Util.doWithClassLoader(Util.java:467)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.JobExecutionService.initExecution(JobExecutionService.java:241)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.operation.InitExecutionOperation.run(InitExecutionOperation.java:73)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.Operation.call(Operation.java:189)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.call(OperationRunnerImpl.java:272)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:248)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:213)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl.run(OperationExecutorImpl.java:411)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl.runOrExecute(OperationExecutorImpl.java:438)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.doInvokeLocal(Invocation.java:600)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.doInvoke(Invocation.java:579)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.invoke0(Invocation.java:540)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:240)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationBuilderImpl.invoke(InvocationBuilderImpl.java:59)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.MasterContext.invokeOnParticipant(MasterContext.java:264)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.MasterContext.invokeOnParticipants(MasterContext.java:247)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.MasterJobContext.lambda$tryStartJob$2(MasterJobContext.java:231)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.JobCoordinationService.lambda$submitToCoordinatorThread$46(JobCoordinationService.java:1039)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.JobCoordinationService.submitToCoordinatorThread(JobCoordinationService.java:1048)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.JobCoordinationService.submitToCoordinatorThread(JobCoordinationService.java:1038)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.MasterJobContext.tryStartJob(MasterJobContext.java:193)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.JobCoordinationService.tryStartJob(JobCoordinationService.java:948)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.JobCoordinationService.lambda$submitJob$1(JobCoordinationService.java:267)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.JobCoordinationService.lambda$submitToCoordinatorThread$46(JobCoordinationService.java:1039)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.JobCoordinationService.lambda$submitToCoordinatorThread$47(JobCoordinationService.java:1060)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.CompletableFutureTask.run(CompletableFutureTask.java:64)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.CachedExecutorServiceDelegate$Worker.run(CachedExecutorServiceDelegate.java:217)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:76)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:102)
```

Here is the remaining satck:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:197)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1843)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.getPosixFilePermissions(Files.java:2117)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.util.Util.editPermissions(Util.java:502)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.python.PythonServiceContext.makeExecutable(PythonServiceContext.java:142)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.python.PythonServiceContext.setupBaseDir(PythonServiceContext.java:194)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.python.PythonServiceContext.<init>(PythonServiceContext.java:84)
```

Why it is not getting executes, I have installed Python 3.6, Pleas help me out.

Comment: Is that the full stack trace? It seems to be missing the trace of `UnsupportedOperationException`. Try to get the missing piece, and also check the version of Hazelcast Jet and the Python module.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have added missing part, hazelcast jet version is 4.5 and Python is 3.5

Comment: The missing piece of the stack trace resolves the reason: we don't support Python on Windows, unfortunately.

Comment: Oh is that so, any specific reason? will it available in future?

Comment: We have bash scripts that handle init and teardown, that's the main reason currently. Not sure about supporting it later on.

Comment: Ohky I got it, thank you for the response. :)